# Filtering from selectnodes through Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, datetime, selectnodes

I have an XML file that contains expiry of elements along with other attributes. I have to parse the file and figure out all the elements which are to expire in next 50 days through a Powershell script.

Entries in XMl file:

```
<Certificate>
        <Version>3</Version>
        <SignatureAlgorithm>sha1RSA</SignatureAlgorithm>
        <Subject />
        <NotAfter>2017-07-12T09:19:44Z</NotAfter>
        <NotBefore>2016-07-12T09:19:44Z</NotBefore>
        <IsVerified>true</IsVerified>
</Certificate>
```

Now through Powershell, I am trying to do something like this:

```
$ExpiryDate=(GET-DATE).AddDays(50)
$xdoc = [xml] (get-content $InputFile)
$xdoc.SelectNodes("//Certificate/NotAfter[. > $ExpiryDate]")
#$xdoc.Save($ResultsFile)
```

But this doesn't seem to be working. I am not even sure if I need to compare "NotAfter" field as date or string.
Any pointers would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

Without a complete example of your xml input, it's quite difficult to give you a proper answer. However, you can get an idea of how to proceed in the example below:

```
$xml = [xml] @"
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <CertificateList>
        <Certificate>
                <Version>3</Version>
                <SignatureAlgorithm>sha1RSA</SignatureAlgorithm>
                <Subject />
                <NotAfter>2017-07-12T09:19:44Z</NotAfter>
                <NotBefore>2016-07-12T09:19:44Z</NotBefore>
                <IsVerified>true</IsVerified>
        </Certificate>
        <Certificate>
                <Version>3</Version>
                <SignatureAlgorithm>sha1RSA</SignatureAlgorithm>
                <Subject />
                <NotAfter>2014-05-12T09:19:44Z</NotAfter>
                <NotBefore>2016-03-12T09:19:44Z</NotBefore>
                <IsVerified>true</IsVerified>
        </Certificate>
    </CertificateList>
"@

$ExpiryDate=(Get-Date).AddDays(50)
$xml.CertificateList.Certificate | ?{ [DateTime] $_.NotAfter -gt $ExpiryDate }
```